# How to preview JP2 and J2K images on Nautilus and Nemo?

Tags: thumbnails, jpeg

I have a number of JPEG-2000 `.jp2` and `.j2k` images that I want to preview on Nautilus or Nemo. How can I tell the file managers to create thumbnails for those files?

Answer (score 3):

Some methods for previewing JPEG-2000 images that work on Nautilus, Nemo, and Caja.

### Method 1: Use `opj_decompress`

---

1. Install `libopenjp2-tools`

   ```
   sudo apt install libopenjp2-tools
   ```

   This package comes with the tools and codecs needed to convert JP2 and J2K images to PNG thumbnails, namely `opj_decompress`, `opj_dump`, and `libopenjp2-7`.

   **Notes:**

   - `libopenjp2-tools` is not available on Ubuntu 14.10 and earlier.
   - If you are on Ubuntu 18.04 or later, you may have to install `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin` (which is usually pre-installed):

     ```
     sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin
     ```

     This package provides `gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer` which will be used to resize the PNGs generated by `opj_decompress` to a more suitable size for thumbnails.
2. Get the **mime-types** of JP2 and J2K images

   - Right-click a JP2 or J2K image, select *Properties*.
   - On the *Basic* tab, take note of what is in the parentheses for the *Type* field. In my case (Ubuntu 20.04), it's `image/jp2` for JP2 images and `image/x-jp2-codestream` for J2K and J2C images.

   Alternatively, you can use `xdg-mime` to get these mime-types. For example, if you have `example.jp2` and `example.j2k` in `~/Pictures`, issue these commands:

   ```
   xdg-mime query filetype ~/Pictures/example.jp2
   xdg-mime query filetype ~/Pictures/example.j2k
   ```
3. Create a **thumbnailer script** for JP2 and J2K images

   - Create a file named `jp2-thumbnailer-bin` in `/usr/local/bin`:

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/local/bin/jp2-thumbnailer-bin
     ```
   - Copy the following script (based on the method from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223606/1062200)) into the file (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into `nano` window):

     ```bsh
     #!/bin/bash

     sInFile="$1"
     nThumbSize="$2"
     sOutFile="$3"

     # Get the dimensions of the input image
     sInfo="$(opj_dump -i "$sInFile")"
     sSize="$(echo "$sInfo" | grep x1 | sed -r 's|.*x1=(.*), y1=(.*)|\1\t\2|')"
     nWidth="$(echo "$sSize" | cut --fields=1)"
     nHeight="$(echo "$sSize" | cut --fields=2)"

     # Get the large dimension of the input image
     if((nWidth>nHeight)); then
         nLargeSize="$nWidth"
     else
         nLargeSize="$nHeight"
     fi

     # Generate output thumbnail;
     # Images larger than the default thumbnail size (256x256 or
     # 128x128 pixels) are scaled down so their large dimension
     # is at most 256 or 128 pixels. This significantly reduces
     # thumbnail generation time.
     if((nLargeSize<=nThumbSize)); then
         /usr/bin/opj_decompress -i "$sInFile" -o "$sOutFile".png
     else
         nResolutions="$(echo "$sInfo" | grep numresolutions | cut --delimiter='=' --fields=2 | sort --general-numeric-sort | sed 1q)"
         nReduce="$(echo "f=l($nLargeSize/$nThumbSize)/l(2);scale=0;f/1" | bc -l)"
         if((nReduce<nResolutions)); then
             nReduceFactor="$nReduce"
         else
             nReduceFactor="$((nResolutions-1))"
         fi
         /usr/bin/opj_decompress -i "$sInFile" -r "$nReduceFactor" -o "$sOutFile".png
     fi
     if [[ -e /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer ]]; then
         /usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s "$nThumbSize" "$sOutFile".png "$sOutFile"
         rm "$sOutFile".png
     else
         mv "$sOutFile".png "$sOutFile"
     fi
     ```
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano` and return to the terminal.
   - Next, make the file executable with:

     ```
     sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jp2-thumbnailer-bin
     ```

   **Note:** If you use Nemo or Caja, you can actually put the script somewhere in your home directory (e.g.  `~/.local/bin`) and run commands like the above without `sudo`. If you use Nautilus, however, you can only do so if `libgnome-desktop` being used by Nautilus is older than *3.28.2*. To get the version number of `libgnome-desktop`, issue this command:

   ```
   apt list --installed | grep libgnome-desktop | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d '-' -f 1
   ```
4. Create a **thumbnailer entry** for JP2 and J2K images

   - First, create a folder named `thumbnailers` in `~/.local/share`.

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/.local/share/thumbnailers
     ```
   - Create a file named `jp2.thumbnailer` in that folder.

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/thumbnailers/jp2.thumbnailer
     ```
   - Copy these lines into the file (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into `nano` window):

     ```conf
     [Thumbnailer Entry]
     Exec=/usr/local/bin/jp2-thumbnailer-bin %i %s %o
     MimeType=image/jp2;image/x-jp2-codestream;
     ```
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`.

   **Notes:**

   - Put the mime-types found earlier in the third line listed above (the `MimeType` key); separate each mime-type with a semicolon (`;`) and optionally end the line with a semicolon.
   - If you want thumbnails for JP2 and J2K images to be available to all users, place this thumbnailer entry in `/usr/share/thumbnailers` instead of `~/.local/share/thumbnailers`:

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/jp2.thumbnailer
     ```
   - A GUI text editor like `gedit` or `xed` can also be used to create and edit the thumbnailer entry. However, if you plan to place it in `/usr/share/thumbnailers`, using `nano` is [highly recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).
5. **Enable thumbnailing** for JP2 images

   The file manager may disable thumbnailing for JP2 images. To check whether this is the case, issue one of these commands, for Nautilus, Nemo, and Caja respectively:

   ```
   gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers disable
   gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.thumbnailers disable
   gsettings get org.mate.thumbnailers disable
   ```

   If the result is `[]` or `['']`, then the file manager does not disable thumbnailing for any file types (and you can go straight to step 6). However, if the result is `['image/jp2']`, then thumbnailing for JP2 images is disabled. To re-enable it, issue one of these commands (for Nautilus, Nemo, and Caja respectively):

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers disable "[]"
   gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.thumbnailers disable "[]"
   gsettings set org.mate.thumbnailers disable "[]"
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use *dconf Editor*:

   - First, install `dconf-editor`:

     ```
     sudo apt install dconf-editor
     ```
   - Open *dconf Editor*, then go to one of these places (for Nautilus, Nemo, and Caja respectively):

     - *org* → *gnome* → *desktop* → *thumbnailers* → *disable*.
     - *org* → *cinnamon* → *desktop* → *thumbnailers* → *disable*.
     - *org* → *mate* → *desktop* → *thumbnailers* → *disable*.
   - Turn off *Use default value*.
   - Change the value in the *Custom value* box from `['image/jp2']` to either `[]` or `['']`.
   - Click *Apply* in the bottom-right corner and close *dconf Editor*.
6. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager

   - First, fully close the file manager with one of these commands:

     ```
     nautilus -q
     nemo -q
     caja -q
     ```
   - Next, delete cached failed thumbnails:

     ```
     rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
     ```
   - Optionally, delete all cached thumbnails (if you previously used unoptimized thumbnailer entries or scripts that created large thumbnails):

     ```
     rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
     ```
   - Finally, reopen the file manager. JP2 and J2K images should have their thumbnails now.

### Method 2: Use `convert`

---

`convert` can be used to create thumbnails for JP2 and J2K images on Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 20.10 and later.

1. Install `imagemagick` which provides the `convert` tool

   ```
   sudo apt install imagemagick
   ```
2. Get the **mime-types** of JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 2)
3. Create a **thumbnailer entry** for JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 4 for details)

   The contents of `~/.local/share/thumbnailers/jp2.thumbnailer` with `convert` as the thumbnailer program:

   ```conf
   [Thumbnailer Entry]
   Exec=/usr/bin/convert %i -thumbnail %sx%s png:%o
   MimeType=image/jp2;image/x-jp2-codestream;
   ```
4. **Enable thumbnailing** for JP2 images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 5)
5. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 6)

### Method 3: Use `gm`

---

`gm` supports JPEG-2000 images on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04.

1. Install `graphicsmagick` which provides the `gm` tool

   ```
   sudo apt install graphicsmagick
   ```
2. Get the **mime-types** of JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 2)
3. Create a **thumbnailer entry** for JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 4 for details)

   The contents of `~/.local/share/thumbnailers/jp2.thumbnailer` with `gm` as the thumbnailer program:

   ```conf
   [Thumbnailer Entry]
   Exec=/usr/bin/gm convert %i -thumbnail %sx%s png:%o
   MimeType=image/jp2;image/x-jp2-codestream;
   ```
4. **Enable thumbnailing** for JP2 images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 5)
5. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 6)

### Method 4: use `totem-video-thumbnailer`

---

`totem-video-thumbnailer` can thumbnail JP2 and J2K images on Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

1. Install `totem` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`

   ```
   sudo apt install totem gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
   ```

   `totem` provides `totem-video-thumbnailer`, while `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` comes with the codecs needed by `totem-video-thumbnailer` to handle JP2 and J2K images.

   **Note:** `totem` is the default video player on GNOME desktops so it is pre-installed on Ubuntu. `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` is *not* pre-installed, however, probably because it's only a *suggested* package for `totem`.
2. Get the **mime-types** of JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 2)
3. Create a **thumbnailer entry** for JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 4 for details)

   The contents of `~/.local/share/thumbnailers/jp2.thumbnailer` with `totem-video-thumbnailer` as the thumbnailer program:

   ```conf
   [Thumbnailer Entry]
   Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
   MimeType=image/jp2;image/x-jp2-codestream;
   ```
4. **Enable thumbnailing** for JP2 images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 5)
5. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 6)

### Method 5: Use `ffmpeg`

---

`ffmpeg` supports JP2 and J2K images on Ubuntu 16.04 and later.

1. Install `ffmpeg`

   ```
   sudo apt install ffmpeg
   ```
2. Get the **mime-types** of JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 2)
3. Create a **thumbnailer entry** for JP2 and J2K images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 4 for details)

   The contents of `~/.local/share/thumbnailers/jp2.thumbnailer` with `ffmpeg` as the thumbnailer program:

   ```conf
   [Thumbnailer Entry]
   Exec=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i %i -filter scale=%s:%s:force_original_aspect_ratio=1 -f apng %o
   MimeType=image/jp2;image/x-jp2-codestream;
   ```
4. **Enable thumbnailing** for JP2 images (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 5)
5. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager (see *Use opj_decompress*, step 6)

### Summary

---

| Tested on → | Ubuntu 14.04 | Ubuntu 16.04 | Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04; Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon; Ubuntu MATE 20.04 | Ubuntu 20.10, 21.04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *opj_decompress* | N/A | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| *convert* | ✔️ | ❌️ | ❌️ | ✔️ |
| *gm* | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌️ | ❌️ |
| *totem-video-thumbnailer* | ❌️ | ❌️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| *ffmpeg* | N/A | ✔️ | ✔️ | ✔️ |

**Note:** Using `opj_decompress` or `totem-video-thumbnailer` is recommended as they offer significantly faster decompression speed and produce smaller thumbnails.